# Перенести большой .txt файл в базу данных (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

У меня есть большой .txt файл, в котором данные хранятся в формате:
Строка1\n
Строка2\n
... 
Мне необходимо чтобы каждая строка была отдельной записью в таблице. Какие методы реализации посоветуете?

Comment: "Прямого" способа перенести - не существует. Прийдется бить на части средствами какого либо языка.

Answer (score 2):

Родной `LOAD DATA INFILE`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
  'myfile.txt'
INTO TABLE
  mytable (
    `data_column`
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat yourscript.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r; do
  line="$REPLY"
  echo "INSERT INTO yourtable (yourcolumnname) VALUES ('$line')" |mysql yourdb
done

$ cat yourfile.txt |./yourscript
```